# Forbidden 403 - Only on 1 function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, wkhtmltopdf

I am currently deploying my web application to a webserver with HTTPS certificate.
The app works correctly on the server and also outside it's local network. 
Except for 1 function, which returns. This only happens when you're outside it's local network. If you do this request on the server directly it works perfectly.

> Fordbidden 403 - You don't have permission to access /SomeFolder/TimeRegistration/GeneratePDF on this server.

Now, the GeneratePDF function does require some access to some folders, so that's maybe why this error occurs but I made sure to add permissions to IIS_IUSRS.

Here is the GeneratePDF function;

```
 public ActionResult GeneratePDF(DateTime? FirstDate = null, DateTime? LastDate = null)
    {
        var VendId = Session["VendId"] as string;
        string ShopDoc = "";
        DateTime updatedFirstDate = FirstDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
        DateTime updatedLastDate = LastDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now);
        int weekNum = updatedFirstDate.DayOfYear / 7 + 1;
        var originalCshtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\somefolder\somefolder\somefolder\Views\PDF\Index.cshtml");

        var myModel = new MyViewModel();
        myModel.TimeRegisters = Utility.Utilities.GetTimeRegisters( updatedFirstDate, updatedLastDate, VendId);
        myModel.WeekNumber = weekNum;
        myModel.ShopDocCode = ShopDoc;
        myModel.GetOrdNr = Utility.Utilities.GetOrdNr(ShopDoc);
        myModel.FromDate = updatedFirstDate;
        myModel.TillDate = updatedLastDate;
        //Update de Timereg -> procesInd = 1.
        var verify = Utility.Utilities.VerifyTimereg(updatedFirstDate, updatedLastDate, VendId);

        var compiledHtml = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(originalCshtml, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), null, myModel);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\temp\\mypdf.html", compiledHtml);
        try
        {
            var p = Process.Start("C:\\temp\\wkhtmltopdf.exe", "C:\\temp\\mypdf.html C:\\temp\\mypdf.pdf");
            p.WaitForExit(10000);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string path = "C://temp//log.txt";
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                string createText = "Created Logfile." + Environment.NewLine;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, createText);
            }
                using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                {
                    string createText = DateTime.Now + " exception: " + ex + " + " + Environment.NewLine;
                    outputFile.WriteLine(createText);
                }
        }

        //    return File("file.pdf", "application/pdf");
        return File("C:\\temp\\mypdf.pdf", "application/pdf", "weeknummer: " + weekNum + ".pdf");
    }
```

Edit:

I removed the controller content and replaced it with a simple return json
but that gives me the exact same error.

I think it has something to do with the way we get to the controller(windows location using JS)

```
window.location.href = appPath + "/TimeRegistration/GeneratePDF?FirstDate=" + firstday + "&LastDate=" + lastday;
```

Comment: Presumably you've checked your log file for any caught exceptions?

Comment: Didn't see any exceptions in the log.

Comment: You're going to have to debug this one your side. As you said yourself, it's most likely an OS permissions issue. Check IIS (or whatever webserver) and OS logs.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Do you think that JS Window.location.href could cause the error? seems like it :/